# Create managed property via powershell?

Tags: 2010, powershell

Is this possible to do via powershell?

http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/01/create-a-content-type-search-refinement-panel-in-sharepoint-2010.html#comment-23134

there is nothing to improve in the question, I need to create a managed property  via powershell, the link shows how to do it visually but doesnt show how to do it via powershell, the real question is that, I know its possible, I just dont know the spcmdlets to use for this and the syntax

Comment: Please put the pertinent information in your question rather than just linking to an article, so that the question can be understood on its own. It will be  closed for now, but don't worry - once you have improved the question  flag a moderator and it can be reopened. See our [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) for general guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: there is nothing to improve in the question, I need to create a content type via powershell, the link shows how to do it visually.

Comment: Your question title talks about a managed property. If you explain what you are trying to do, with possibly a link to provide background information, you will have a good chance of getting someone to help. The linked article has nothing to do with creating a content type, as far as I can tell.

Comment: that was a typo, I edited it, indeed I need to create a managed property to The content type property.

Comment: Is the question looking to create Content Types using PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do it via powershell.

If you want to create a managed property for Sharepoint Enterprise Search via Powershell, Use :

```
New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty
```

Check out [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608089.aspx) for the usage and parameters.

If you want to create a managed property for Fast Search for SharePoint via Powershell, Use:

```
New-FASTSearchMetadataManagedProperty
```

Check out [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393789.aspx) for the usage and parameters.

Comment: Could you expand on that other than just saying Yes?

Comment: lol, what an answer.

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, rather than just taking the mickey, even if the question deserved it. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: Guys, I hope I answered the question now.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/create-taxonomy-group-termset-and-term-in-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell/) is an example.

You can also use [Command Builder](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/TechNet/en-us/Office/media/WindowsPowerShell/WindowsPowerShellCommandBuilder.html) to build some powershell commands.

Comment: I asked content type, not term sets. thx